Is there a visual studio plugin to highlight or color code only specific XML attributes?
I'm looking for a VS plugin to highlight or color code only specifically configured XML attributes (or potentially other nodes). Does anybody know of anything like this? My use case is a domain specific language that is formulated as an XML config that tells a program what to do during execution, and I'd like the capability to highlight certain commands or parameters.
<!-- e.g. highlight description in green, factors 1 and 2 in blue -->
<AlgorithmMultiply description="Multiply previous result by two"
                   factor1="PreviousResult"
                   factor2="2.0"/> 

